# can't get data by id in codeigniter through json

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, codeigniter-3

I am fetching the `sub_regions` name on the basis of `region_id`.
Doing it through ajax, So after joining the region and sub_region table I am getting the results in the *network* of google chrome console. That means the query and everything else is working good.

Now the problem is :

1. The data is not printing on specified Div tag
2. The data I am getting is of all the `sub_regions`, its not ID specific `sub_region`

   **JavaScript:**

   ```
   <script>
    $("li a").click(function() {
   var x = $(this).attr('id'); // this is getting the id of the region from region links
   if (x.length > 0) {
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: "id=" + x,
       url: "http://localhost/sitename/autocomplete/GetRegionName",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(result) {
           $.each(result, function(i, v) {

             // For each record in the returned array
             $('#result').append(v.name); // specified name as to display only the name of sub_region, not everything else
             alert(v.name);
           });
         } // end success
     }); // end ajax
   } // if condition ends
   return false;
    });
   </script>
   ```

**PHP:**

```
    <?php
    // This is the controller
    public function GetRegionName(){
            $keyword=$this->input->post('keyword');
            $data=$this->regioncomplete->GetRow($keyword);        
            echo json_encode($data);
        }   
    // This is the Model where i have joined 2 tables "regions" and "subregions" and declared that region ID = Sub region ID
            class Regioncomplete extends CI_Model{
            public function GetRow($keyword) {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('regions');
            $this->db->join('sub_regions', 'regions.id = sub_regions.region_id');        
            $this->db->order_by('sub_regions.id', 'DESC');
            $this->db->like("sub_regions.name", $keyword);
            return $this->db->get()->result_array();
        }
    }
    ?>
```

I am getting the result in *Network* like this

```
{id: "2", code: "CF", name: "California", country_id: "1", region_id: "2"}
{id: "1", code: "ST", name: "Seattle", country_id: "1", region_id: "1"}
```

Comment: data : { 'keyword' : x }  maybe?

Comment: @歐津柏 don't know what's that gonna be... what will that do??

Comment: oh sorry~ I didn't see the result you got, it looks like you have a response from php script, I think you should check what you are getting in 'v' using typeof(), and also does it print out the value of v.name of you use console.log(v.name)

Comment: why `$keyword=$this->input->post('keyword');` not `$keyword=$this->input->post('id');` ??

Comment: @歐津柏 i did as you said. The alert function returned alert box with "object" , and each time i clicked ok in alert box.., in console i got all the names of sub regions.

Comment: @Ata i get no response when i use the 'id' there. it returns [] No Properties

Comment: @Ripudaman Singh then i guess the answer to problem 1 is $('#result') isn't a valid selector, maybe you got repeated id="result" in your html

Comment: @Ata a Good point though, i will just go through this again. Thanks man

Comment: @歐津柏 Oh yes! Just checked that the id result was repeated in the file and moreover it was set to display none! silly mistake, thank you very much for your help.
Now am getting a cluster of all the sub regions, not by ID

Comment: As for problem 2, can you be more specific? I only understand you are getting results from the table 'sub-region' but i don't understand  its not ID specific sub_region, as i can see in the response there is a 'id' property

Comment: @歐津柏 by that i mean it should display sub_region related to the region_id.
If var x = 1, it should show the region as "seattle" as it has region_id 1,
If var x = 2, it should show the region as "california" as it has region_id 2...
and so on..
i am getting the desired property of var x but its not showing up the related region

Comment: so you mean you are getting the whole table of results but instead of one?
then your query should be using

 $this->db->where("sub_regions.id", $keyword);

instead of 

 $this->db->like("sub_regions.name", $keyword);

that is, if your reference is sub_regions.id not sub_regions.name

Comment: @歐津柏 it returns [] No Properties. And yes my reference is DB Table Sub_regions region_id column...
i am storing the id of region_id and if region_id = sub_region region_id, then i will get the name of the city.
Should i paste 1 row of sql table structure if this is getting confusing?

Comment: @歐津柏 actually, it solved it. i used $keyword=$this->input->post('id'); as suggested Thank you so very much for your help bro!

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function (result) {
$.each(result, function(key, item) {
    var get_result = "<p>"+item.name+"</p><br/>";
    $(get_result).appendTo('#result');
});
}
```

OR

```
success: function (result) {
for (var i = 0; i < data.result; i++) {
 var get_result = "<p>"+data[i].name+"</p> <br/>";
     $(get_result).appendTo('#result');
}
```

}

check this out

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token > with both of em

Comment: $(get_result).appendTo('#result');  plz update& var get_result = "<p>"+data[i].name+"</p> <br/>"; this

Comment: The issue is solved with help of  歐津柏 . He guided me through this in the comments.
Thank you so much for your valuable time just for helping me out :)